# ListView not able to scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have collapsing toolbar with imageView inside it and a listview to display items
Here's the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout_profilePage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_ProfilePage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_UserImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_ProfilePage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_userDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="15dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/fab_EditProfile"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout_profilePage"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" /></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am not able to scroll in the listview and moreover the toolbar is not collapsing.
Can you also tell me how to automatically set colors to the toolbar depending on the image colors.

Comment: P.S. ask single question in a single question :)

Comment: Don't use ListView with CoordinatorLayout  it may give you strange behaviour Use Recyclerview in place of ListView.

Comment: use recycleview instead of listview. this is more faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scrollable child must support Nested Scrolling. ListView supports nested scrolling only on 21+, so you must use RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Add your listview / recycleview under NestedScrollView.
Replace your layout code with

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"><android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout_profilePage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_ProfilePage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_UserImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/header"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_ProfilePage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listView_userDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="15dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/fab_EditProfile"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout_profilePage"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope it work.

Comment: please mention what you have changed in your answer.

Comment: i added the nested scrollView but it now shows only 1 item in the listview

Comment: Try to use Recyclerview in place of ListView. check updated answer. i think it's better.

Answer (score 0):

i had faced the same problem and i resolved with using RecyclerView and the reason is as said by @Marius.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the below code in your xml layout file.

```
    <Listview 
    ............
    ............
    android:scrollbars=”vertical”
    ........../>
```